# How would I get input from a QLineEdit in a Qt Creator GUI?

Tags: c++, qt

I am new to Qt Creator programming, and I am having an extremely difficult time finding decent resources to help get an absolute beginner started. I want to create a simple window that allows the user to input a string into a QLineEdit box, then pick a value from a drop-down box (QComboBox). They then click a push button that takes the input from these sources, displays the input in the window, and writes it to a file.

I have absolutely no idea how to take input from these two sources and collect it when the button is pushed, or how to get it to display on the screen. I feel a simple exercise like this would cover the basics on how to use Qt very well. If anybody could give me some simple example code, or link me to any sort of tutorial for ABSOLUTE beginners which will help me accomplish this specific task that would be great!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Qt Creator, click `Help | Contents`, and then `Qt Reference Documentation | Tutorials and Examples`. There you will find dozens of example projects that you can try. Take a day or two to look through them before starting on your own project.